# Work done should be positive but it is coming out to be negative?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work, conventions

I have described a question in which this problem arises in the image below:

[image]

Comment: You set the bounds of your integral as from $l/3$ to $0$.  The positive direction is usually defined as up.  Shouldn't it be from $-l/3$ to $0$

Comment: Bounds should be from "initital value of x" to "final value" i.e. from l/3 to 0.. even if we put it as -l/3 to 0, it would not change the answer

Comment: @tmwilson26 is correct. If you define your positive direction such that you integrate from l/3 to zero, your external force is in the negative direction! Check your directions, force sign and your integration boundaries, it is what is giving you the wrong sign

Comment: If you imagine straightening out the corner so that the spring lays flat, it's easier to see that the displacement of the end of the spring goes from $-l/3$ to $0$.

Comment: Whoops, I missed the $x^2$ issue ...

Answer (score 1):

Okay, point taken about the $x^2$ value from your comments, but the problem here is going to stem from the definition of your coordinates system.  The way that you have it right now, the initial position of the chain is $x=l/3$ and the top of the table is $x=0$.  This defines force of gravity being in the *positive* $x$ direction.  That means that the external force that is applied is negative.  So you should replace $g$ with $-g$.  If you redefine the coordinate system my way, with gravity being negative pointing downward, you'd need to be careful about how you define the mass term $x/l m$.  In this case, you'd end up with negative mass (since x starts at $-l/3$), so this term would have to be $-\frac{x}{l m}$

Comment: I have considered the upward direction as positive. The magnitude of my force is mgx/l and it is in upward direction.Small displacement dx is also in upward direction.This has nothing to do with gravity and its direction.

Comment: Direction is critical, and you have to stay consistent.  You defined your force as being in the upward direction, and it is positive for all values of $x$ considered here.  Yet, your displacement as you defined it goes **from** $+l/3$ **to** $0$.  This gives $\Delta x = x_f - x_i = -l/3$, which is negative.  Your force and displacement do not point in the same direction (as you have defined them).